# Assign Nested Keys and Values in Dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to assign nested values to a dictionary. I have simplified my question for ease of understanding:

```
Data = {}   
day1 = 'March12'
day2 = 'March14'
e1 = 'experiment1'
e2 = 'experiment2'

Data[day1][e1] = 4
```

But the `Data[day1][e1] = 4` command does not function (for the same reason as `test = {} ; test["foo"]["bar"] = 0`). Is there a workaround to do this?

I tried to do things like:

```
me1 = {e1 : 4}
me2 = {e2 : 5}
Data = {day1 : me1}
Data = {day2 : me2}
```

But I couldn't succeed; all the things I wrote have somehow overwritten the existing values or were not as I would like to have. I'm probably missing out something...

Some additional notes: At the begininng don't have any info about the length of the dictionary, or how it exactly looks like. And instead of the value `4`, I assign an object as a value. I need to use such a structure (`Data[day1][e1]`) because I have to assign the objects to their keys inside a loop.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to store a *new* dictionary inside of `Data` to make this work:

```
Data[day1] = {}
Data[day1][e1] = 4
```

but normally you'd first test to see if that dictionary is there yet; using `dict.setdefault()` to make that a one-step process:

```
if day1 not in Data
    Data[day1] = {}
Data[day1][e1] = 4
```

The [`collections.defaultdict()` type](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) automates that process:

```
from collections import defaultdict

Data = defaultdict(dict)
Data[day1][e1] = 4
```

The `day1` key doesn't exist yet, but the `defaultdict()` object then calls the configured constructor (`dict` here) to produce a new value for that key as needed.

Comment: This is cool for a single level, but can it be easily generalised to many levels? I guess defaultdict(defaultdict(dict)) only gets us one extra level?

Comment: @BenFarmer: extending this to unlimited levels is called *auto-vivification* and all you need is a separate factory: `factory = lambda: defaultdict(factory)`, then `data = defaultdict(factory)`. Note the recursive definition of the factory..

Answer (score 4):

You have to create each empty dict for each key like

`Data = {}`

`Data['day1'] = {}`

`Data['day1']['e1'] = 4`